# Efficiency of ajax update using @form vs @parent vs specific ids vs p:autoUpdate

Tags: jsf, primefaces

PrimeFaces Showcase includes this (slightly amended) code as a demonstration in the use of `p:focus`.

```xhtml
<h:form id="form">
    <p:focus id="focus" context="panel"/>

    <p:messages id="messages"/>

    <h:panelGrid id="panel" columns="3" cellpadding="7">
        <p:outputLabel for="username" value="Username"/>
        <p:inputText id="username" value="#{focusView.username}" required="true" />
        <p:message for="username"/>

        <p:outputLabel for="email" value="Email"/>
        <p:inputText id="email" value="#{focusView.email}" required="true" />
        <p:message for="email"/>
    </h:panelGrid>

    <p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{focusView.save}"
                     update="@parent" />
</h:form>
```

The `update="@parent"` clause could have been written in several ways and have the same effect.

1. update="@form"
2. update="@parent"
3. update="focus messages panel"
4. update="focus messages username username:@next email email:@next"
5. using `p:autoUpdate` on p:focus, p:messages and p:panelgrid (no update=)
6. using `p:autoUpdate` on p:focus, p:messages, username and its message and on email and its message

(Plus others.) I could argue that option 1 is the best and least error prone from a programmer's and support perspective. However which is most efficient and why? Are there any other factors that should be considered in choosing an option?

Comment: i personally like a mix of all ;D
Using autoUpdate for focus and messages is IMO the nicest way.
Updating `@parent` or `@form` is less error-prone and more maintainable then using IDs. Of course updating single elements with IDs is better from performance perspective.

Comment: Agree with everything @tandraschko said!